Why is my CPU utilization limited to 0.4 GHz?
I've seen other similar questions, but none meet my exact circumstances so I wanna make sure I do the right thing before investing money in a new fan/charger or potentially messing something up trying to fix it.
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3550H
Laptop: HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-ec0013dx
With that aside, around a month and a half ago, I went to plug my charger in and heard a quiet pop noise upon entry at the port. After hearing it, my charger wouldn't work again unless I held it at the perfect angle. I bought a new charger, 135W just like the one that came with my laptop. It was able to charge again, but now my CPU is limited to 0.4 GHz. If I unplug my charger, it goes back up to the base speed. Task Manager CPU Performance
I tried changing the performance mode, setting the maximum & minimum CPU usage to 100%, and checking the BIOS. Based off the responses I've seen from other posts, it's either the CPU's fan, or the charger not working properly. If it's the charger, should I buy a new one with the same wattage or one with higher watts?
I've had this laptop since 2019, and I'm dependent on it for school and also just playing games. I do move it between my bed and my desk, I'm not sure if that could effect it. It's basically only been used while on the charger, prior to the damage.
I'm open to any suggestions, and I apologize if this is considered a duplicate post or if the formatting is messed up. Thank you and have a great day.

https://superuser.com/search?q=0.4+ghz and also related https://superuser.com/search?q=0.8+ghz. Look through those first and try some of the solutions and then [edit] your question tellinnus what you tried and what didn't work.

I'm not an expert here - but "heard a quiet pop noise upon entry at the port" makes me wonder if you blew up a capacitor on the motherboard.  Speculating even more wildly, that could cause the power to not be clean at high current (caps smooth voltage), and maybe your system is smart enough to detect this and limit the CPU to its minimum power draw?

Many laptops cap the cpu speed when it believes it's not connected to a charger, or believes the connected charger is insufficiently capable of supplying the whole system at max power draw. Wouldn't surprise me if your laptop, for some unknown reason, don't trust your new charger and cap the cpu :( how long since the pc was bought?  Edit: I agree with davidgo's blown capacitor theory

This is not a permanent solution. Only temporarily by Disable BD PROCHOT sensor.
I have the same problem as you from 2020 until now. CPU ClockSpeed drops to 0.4 GHz when in AC mode.
In my PC, This is because there is a motherboard component that is malfunction. I haven't fixed it yet. alternatively I just use software to disable BD PROCHOT sensor at startup.
In Windows OS, I use ThrottleStop and make it Autorun at startup using Task Scheduler.
This little app fixes the problem temporarily. You can try it.
This screenshot in AC Mode before Using the App.

In Linux OS, I haven't found a ready-to-use application. So, i use like Turn Off BD PROCHOT with additional settings to make Bash Script Autorun.

While a "good enough" solution for many it does not actually fix the underlying problem. The problem is that something in your system is telling your firmware that it is overheating or in an otherwise abnormal state. Your firmware then uses the BD PROCHOT signal to limit processor power until the fault is rectified. Granted in some cases this has been a firmware bug, but in many it is telling you that something is overheating and it's worth investigating what exactly is going on. https://www.hwinfo.com/ is a good tool that can show you most sensors in a system.

Well. Because I don't want to repair the hardware yet, I consider this just a temporary solution (FREE) until I actually repair the motherboard which costs money

And that is fair enough, I just wanted anyone who sees this to have a caveat that this is not a true "fix" and people should really do more in depth faultfinding. Turning off BD PROCHOT simply stops the firmware from controlling the processor throttling mechanism so that it will only throttle if the processor itself is overheating. Inside laptops which tend to have shared cooling systems it has the potential of making a problem worse as it could compound the problem in another device with more heat. I don't deny it is a solution, but it is one that needs further investigation IMO.

Good Idea. Thakns.
